# Flappy Bird Style Game in Space Setting

Tags: python, pygame

Simple game where you control space shuttle with mouse click and try to avoid meteors moving in random speed toward you. There are some things I am still developing like rotation and menus, but wanted to get some tips/recommendations on what I have so far.

Thank you in advance!

```
# Import pygame and random
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine 
pygame.init()

#Define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Define done 
done = False

# Define function to create new meteor
def create_meteor():
    meteor = Meteor(WHITE, width, height)
    meteor_sprites_list.add(meteor)

# Define player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, filename, color, HW, HH):
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
        # Set background color to transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey(color)


        # Make top-left corner the passed in locatin 
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((HW, HH), self.image.get_size())

        # Gravity
        self.dy = 0 


    def ignite(self):
        self.dy = -400

    def update(self, dt, screen):

        # Apply gravity
        self.dy = min(400, self.dy + 40)
        self.rect.y += self.dy * dt


        # What happens if go to border of screen
        if(self.rect.top <= 0):   #top
            self.rect.y = 0
            self.dy = -4
        elif(self.rect.bottom >= height):   #ground
            self.rect.y = (526-self.rect.height)

        #blit image to screen
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Define new clas for meteor
class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Takes in parameters for color, width (x position) , and height (y postion)

        # Call the parent class 
        super().__init__()

        # Make list of image file location
        self.meteor_list = ["meteors/meteor1.png"]

        # Randomly select meteor from above list
        self.new_meteor = random.choice(self.meteor_list)

        # Load graphic that is in file folder  
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.new_meteor).convert_alpha()

        # Set background to transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Random starting location
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width, (width + 300))
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, height)

        # Random movement to the left
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-10,-5)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-4,3)

        # Set angle for rotate attribute

    # ---- Attributes  
    def reset_pos(self, screen):
        # List of meteors
        self.meteor_list = ["meteors/meteor1.png"]

        # Pick random meteor from above list
        self.new_meteor = random.choice(self.meteor_list)

        # Load graphic that is in file folder  
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.new_meteor).convert_alpha()

        # Set background to transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)      

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Reset postion of bad block when they reach the bottom of the screen 
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width, (width +100))
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, height)

        # Random movement to the left
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-10,-5)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-4,3)

    # What meteor does each cycle through
    def update(self): 

        # Add rotation 
        #pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 115)

        # Move bad block down 3 at a time 
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        #blit image to screen
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        # Reset if falls off screen
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.reset_pos(screen)
        if self.rect.top > height:
            self.reset_pos(screen)
        if  self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.reset_pos(screen)

# Class to show the how far rocketship has travelled        
class Distance(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        # Call the parent class 
        super().__init__()

        # Get time since init was called
        time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        # Convert milliseconds to seconds, 1 second = 1 km
        travel_distance = round(time/1000, 2)

        # Format the font to be used 
        font = pygame.font.SysFont ("transistor", 25, True, False)

        # Create text to be displayed
        text = font.render("You've travelled " + str(travel_distance) + " kms", True, WHITE)

        # Center text 
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(HW, HH))

        # Blit text to the screen
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)


# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_size = pygame.image.load("background.png")
# Get dimensions of background
width = background_size.get_width()
height = background_size.get_height() 
HW, HH = width/2, height/2
size = (width, height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
x = 0 

# Load image for star background  
background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
# Seperate becuase error when placed before screen

#Set caption
pygame.display.set_caption("")

# Creates a list of sprites. Each object in program is added to list. Managed by a class called "group"
meteor_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create spaceship 
player = Player("player.png", WHITE, HW, HH)

# Create meteor sprites on the screen     
for i in range(4):
    create_meteor()

#-----Main Program Loop 
while not done:
    dt = clock.tick(30)
    # Main event Loop 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            player.ignite()

#-----Game Logic 

    # Draw background and move to the left
    rel_x = x % width
    screen.blit(background, (rel_x - width, 0))
    if rel_x < width:
        screen.blit(background, (rel_x, 0))
    x -= 2

    # Display text on screen
    Distance()

    # Update Sprites 
    # Update meteor sprite
    meteor_sprites_list.update()
    # Update player sprite
    player.update(dt/1000. , screen)

    # Check to see if player has collided with meteor
    meteor_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, meteor_sprites_list, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

    # Event if player collides with meteor 
    for item in meteor_hit_list:
        print("Shuttle hit")
        create_meteor()
        meteor_hit_list.remove(item)

        # Make into game over screen and display distance

    # Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

# Make sure to quit 
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Good job! Here are my suggestions (roughly ordered from important to less important):

Separate the game logic from the drawing/blitting code. That will make your main loop cleaner and the code will probably be easier to extend. So don't blit the sprite images in their `update` methods.

Sprites in a sprite group can be blitted by calling the `draw` method of the group: `meteor_group.draw(screen)`.
I've renamed the `meteor_sprites_list` to `meteor_group`, because pygame groups are not lists.

If you want to keep the player sprite separate, just blit it in the while loop: `screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)`.

---

Load the images globally or in a separate module, because it's inefficient to load them repeatedly from the hard disk in the main loop. The `self.meteor_list` can also be a global list:

```
PLAYER_SURFACE = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
METEOR_LIST = [
    pygame.image.load("meteors/meteor1.png").convert_alpha(),
    pygame.image.load("meteors/meteor2.png").convert_alpha(),
    # etc.
    ]
# If you have a lot of images, better load them with a for loop and append them.
```

Then choose and assign a random image in the `__init__` method:

```
self.image = random.choice(METEOR_LIST)
```

I'm not sure if your images already have transparent backgrounds, if yes, you can just call `convert_alpha()` and omit this line:

```
self.image.set_colorkey(color)
```

You're loading the `background` image twice. Just replace `background_size` with `background`. And don't forget to convert the surfaces/images, because unconverted surfaces can slow the game down a lot: `background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()`.

---

The `Distance` class can just be a function.
Also, if you pass the coords as the `topleft` argument it doesn't jitter so much: `text.get_rect(topleft=(HW-100, HH))`. Or you could just blit the `text` at these coordinates:  `screen.blit(text, (HW-100, HH))`.

```
def distance(screen):
    """Show how far the rocketship has travelled."""
    # Get time since init was called
    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # Convert milliseconds to seconds, 1 second = 1 km
    travel_distance = round(time/1000, 2)
    text = font.render("You've travelled " + str(travel_distance) + " kms", True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, (HW-100, HH))
```

---

The while loop and the corresponding variables could be put into a `main` function or a class to clean up the global namespace.

---

You've got a lot of comments in your example which make the code a bit more difficult to read. Add comments only if something could be unclear (explain **why** the code is needed). Some comments are even wrong or outdated.

This one is unnecessary, since the code is self-explanatory:

```
# Set caption
pygame.display.set_caption("")
```

This one is more useful:

```
# Reset if falls off screen
if self.rect.right < 0:
    self.reset_pos(screen)
```

---

You don't need to remove the hit meteor from the `meteor_hit_list` because you'll create a new list in the next frame anyway:

```
meteor_hit_list.remove(item)  # Just remove this line.
```

---

To stop the player at the bottom of the screen:

```
elif self.rect.bottom >= height:
    self.rect.bottom = screen.get_height()
```

---

There are some unnecessary parentheses:

```
if(self.rect.top <= 0):

self.rect.y = (526-self.rect.height)
```

---

Take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

And happy coding!