# Mouse Click Controlled Meteor Avoidance Game

Tags: python, pygame

Ongoing development of game. The player is controlled by mouse click to move upward. The goal is to avoid meteors for as long as possible. I would be grateful if someone could critique my code.

Verison 1 can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197603/flappy-bird-style-game-in-space-setting). Since then I have:

- Added intro menu screen
- Added game loop to contain main game logic
- Added health to game, game over screen when health == 0
- Removed unnecessary and redundant comments
- Implemented recommendations found in original post

Still working on:

- Adding rotation to meteors
- Display health with health bar
- Buttons in intro menu

```
# All images found @ http://kenney.nl/assets/space-shooter-extension, http://kenney.nl/assets/space-shooter-redux, and https://www.goldstar.com/events/los-angeles-ca/the-sirens-of-titan-tickets

import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

def game_intro():
    intro = False
    intro_background = pygame.image.load("assets/title_screen.png")
    # Get dimensions of background
    width = background.get_width()
    height = background.get_height() 
    HW, HH = width/2, height/2
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    intro_background = intro_background.convert()

    while not intro: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True 
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                game_loop(background)

        screen.blit(intro_background, (0,0))        
        message_display("Click to take Constant home")
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(15)


    pygame.quit()

def game_loop(background):
    done = False 
    x = 0 
    health = 5 
    while not done:
        dt = clock.tick(30)
        # Main event Loop 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                player.ignite()

        #-----Game Logic 

        # Draw background and move to the left
        rel_x = x % width
        screen.blit(background, (rel_x - width, 0))
        if rel_x < width:
            screen.blit(background, (rel_x, 0))
        x -= 2

        # Check to see if player has collided with meteor
        meteor_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, meteor_group, 
                                                      True)
        # Event if player collides with meteor 
        for item in meteor_hit_list:
            health -= 1
            print("Shuttle hit", health)
            if health == 0:
                game_over()
            create_meteor()               

        distance(screen)
        all_sprites_group.draw(screen)
        meteor_group.update()
        player.update(dt/1000)

        pygame.display.flip()


    pygame.quit()

def game_over():
    exit = False 
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((850,526))


    while not exit: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                game_intro()

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        message_display("GAME OVER! Click to restart")
        pygame.display.update()

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(30)


    pygame.quit()

def create_meteor():
    meteor = Meteor(width, height)
    meteor_group.add(meteor)
    all_sprites_group.add(meteor)

def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("transistor", 25, True, False)
    travel_text = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(travel_text, (HW-150, HH))

def distance(screen):
    """Show how far the rocketship has travelled."""
    # Get time since init was called
    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # Convert milliseconds to seconds, 1 second = 1 km
    travel_distance = round(time/1000, 2)
    message_display("You have travelled " + str(travel_distance) + "  lightyears")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,PLAYER_SURFACE, HW, HH):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = PLAYER_SURFACE            
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(((HW - (PLAYER_SURFACE.get_width())), HH), 
                                       self.image.get_size())

        # Gravity
        self.dy = 0 

    def ignite(self):
        self.dy = -400

    def update(self, dt):

        # Apply gravity
        self.dy = min(400, self.dy + 40)
        self.rect.y += self.dy * dt

        # What happens if go to border of screen
        if self.rect.top <= 0:   # Top
            self.rect.y = 0
            self.dy = -4
        elif self.rect.bottom >= height:   # Bottom
            self.rect.y = 526-self.rect.height

class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = random.choice(METEOR_IMAGES)   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Random starting location
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width, (width + 300))
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, height)

        # Random movement to the left
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-10,-5)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-4,3)

    def reset_pos(self, screen):
        self.image = random.choice(METEOR_IMAGES)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width, (width + 100))
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, height)

        # Random movement to the left
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-10,-5)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-4,3)


    def update(self): 
        # Move meteor
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Reset if falls off screen
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.reset_pos(screen)
        if self.rect.top > height:
            self.reset_pos(screen)
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.reset_pos(screen)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load("assets/background.png")

# Get dimensions of background
width = background.get_width()
height = background.get_height() 
HW, HH = width/2, height/2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
background = background.convert()


PLAYER_SURFACE = pygame.image.load("assets/player.png").convert_alpha()
METEOR_IMAGES = []
METEOR_LIST = [
    "assets/meteors/meteor1.png"...
]
for image in METEOR_LIST:
    METEOR_IMAGES.append(pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha())

pygame.display.set_caption("Return from Titan")

all_sprites_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
meteor_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create spaceship 
player = Player(PLAYER_SURFACE, HW, HH)
all_sprites_group.add(player)

# Create meteor sprites on the screen     
for i in range(4):
    create_meteor()

game_intro()
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I wasn't aware of the connection between stack exchange and stack overflow, so I used a guest username not knowing it would get linked to my account anyway.

Comment: Looks pretty good. For the scenes I'd use a finite state machine similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/) or if you want to keep your scene functions, take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460947/6220679).